# In Excel, how do I give a "TRUE" row (column) filter to FILTER() for a multi-column (row) array

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

In Excel, conditionally filtering rows in a single column array is simple. Something like the following will filter the array only if *condition* is met:

```
=FILTER(A1:A10,IF(condition,filter,TRUE))
```

However, that does not work for a multi-column array. For example, for a 2-column array, the following returns #VALUE!

```
=FILTER(A1:B10,IF(condition,filter,TRUE))
```

Instead, the following is required

```
=FILTER(A1:B10,IF(condition,filter,{TRUE,TRUE}))
```

What is the general form for the second -- TRUE -- branch?
Is it simply a matter of creating a horizontal vector of TRUE values, of length COLUMNS(my_array)? If so, how is that best done?

Comment: I cannot reproduce.  I can cause a false condition and it returns the full array.  Can you provide some test data and expected output as well as show what does not work?

Comment: The second parameter of FILTER() is just true/false - so either Excel expects a formula (that it will evaluate itself to determine the result), or just TRUE or FALSE.  I don't actually think you need the IF ... I suspect you just need to put your "condition" formula as the direct second parameter of the FILTER() function.  Perhaps provide a set of sample data, showing a couple of examples of the results you are expecting from the FILTER()

Comment: OK, thanks for that (although for a second y'all had me thinking I was going insane). It turns out the problem isn't really to do with the conditional, and everything to do with the dimensions of the array being filtered. I'm going to rewrite the question to reflect that; the conditional aspect is what exposes the issue, but it isn't the cause.

Comment: If you condition returns an array of logicals, just `AND` the condition. eg if `condition={TRUE,TRUE}` then `=FILTER(A1:B10,AND(condition))`

Answer (score 0):

You can filter 2D-range or table in both directions, but not at the same time. You must use FILTER function separately for rows and for columns in any order.
Criteria should be formulated for single rows or single columns. You can add criteria (`+` means `OR`) or multiply (`*` means `AND`). Avoid using `AND` or `OR` functions as they produce single results, not arrays, so can be used only on special occasions.
See an example below.
[image: FILTER 2D range]